# Trying to all rows from 4 different tables, Clickhouse doesnt detect table when using union all

Tags: sql, sql-like, clickhouse, redash

So I have 4 subtables all the same schema and I want to show all rows between all the tables so I can have redash convert it into a chart

My current idea was to just have chain of union all, but for some reason, clickhouse doesnt think it exists

```
select * from first 
union all
select * from second
```

results in: "Exception: Table second doesn't exist"

However

```
select * from second
```

works just fine.

is there something that I am missing from this logic?

Comment: try to define the database name explicitly - `select * from db.first union all select * from db.second`.

Comment: it should work. Try with clickhouse-client.

Comment: what version of clickhouse are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, for some reason I had to select from the union of selects

```
select * from (
select * from first
union all
select * from second
...
) group by ...
```

I don't know why it doesn't detect the table with my original method, but it worked out now

I hope someone with a similar issue will find this helpful